# React js show modal dialog when during componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Let's say I have a multistep modal dialog component that appears when the page loads. For each step some settings may be changed which causes the container to re-render. Ideally, this component should only be mounted during componentDidmount. My problem is that the multistep component needs props that are undefined since the fetching of data is also done in componentDidmont().

How can I make sure that the multistep only appears once and has the props it needs?

another problem I have that lets I have an array of strings will map to a react component like this

```
Array [ "FirstComponent", "SecondComponent", "ThridComponent"]
```

so after the FirstComponent is done some props are updated 
and that causes a re-render which will make the array look like this

```
Array ["SecondComponent", "ThridComponent"]
```

I am getting miss-match between the length of the array and current step state

how can i make sure that step state will be in sync with the with the length of the array?

Comment: can you add some snippets of code. What have you tried, what did not work?

Comment: I can't show code due to legal reasons

Comment: Maybe you can check for `undefined` before you put the values, something like `typeof(this.props.somevalue) === "undefined" ? null : this.props.somevalue`. But can't say much as you haven't shared any code.

Comment: My main question is how can I make the modal only appear ones and not re-render becasue the main container re-renders?

Comment: You should keep a flag in the component's state for each modal, just update the flag to `true` for whichever modal you want to display, keep other flags as `false`.